# How to read netcdf4 MinGW?

Tags: mingw, netcdf, netcdf4

To put you in context, I am trying to check an algorithm (known as DINEOF) that fills missing data in raster time series. The algorithm is written in Fortran and I learnt that I need to use MinGW for running it on Win10.

Currently, I am trying to follow this guideline:
http://modb.oce.ulg.ac.be/mediawiki/index.php/DINEOF_for_Windows
But, I find myself struggling with this step:

```
./configure  --disable-netcdf-4  --disable-dap  > config.log
make > make.log
make check > check.log
make install
```

Error / Warning Messages:

```
$ ./configure  --disable-netcdf-4  --disable-dap  > config.log
configure: WARNING: Doxygen not found - documentation will not be built
configure: WARNING: dot not found - will use simple charts in documentation
configure: WARNING: netcdf-4 not enabled; disabling DAP4
```

```
$ make > make.log
In file included from ../include/ncdispatch.h:14:0,
                 from dparallel.c:9:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:345:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__mingw__snprintf'
 extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(snprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
            ^
make[2]: *** [libdispatch_la-dparallel.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

```
$ make check > check.log
In file included from ../include/ncdispatch.h:14:0,
                 from dparallel.c:9:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:345:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__mingw__snprintf'
 extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(snprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
            ^
make[1]: *** [libdispatch_la-dparallel.lo] Error 1
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: You ask about NetCDF 4, but explicitly have `--disable-netcdf-4` when configuring?

Comment: @francescalus I have no previous experience with compiling Fortran code and I may have framed my request in the wrong way. From what I understand the guideline instructions will start by setting a directory, reading a netcdf4 file and then applying the DINEOF algorithm on it. Nonetheless, can you perhaps tell me possible reasons why those code lines did not work for me? (even a general answer would be of help)

Comment: From the look of the commands presented in the question, you are trying to build the NetCDF package (this part of which is written in C) rather than use the package as part of your Fortran program. If that's correct, then I'm afraid I can't really help you; someone who understands more of the internals of the NetCDF library may be able to help but may need more details about the system you are using (such as versions of your toolchain in use and NetCDF you want to install).

Answer (score 0):

Instructions you're using are for building NetCDF 4.5.0, but latest is 4.7.4, which can be built with cmake. For me the following works with GCC 10.2.0 from http://winlibs.com/ (provided prerequisites are present):

```
wget -c https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/ftp/netcdf-c-4.7.4.tar.gz
tar xfz netcdf-c-4.7.4.tar.gz
cd netcdf-c-4.7.4

# fix conflicting getopt in include/XGetopt.h
mv include/XGetopt.h include/XGetopt.h.bak &&
echo "#include <getopt.h>" > include/XGetopt.h

cmake.exe -Wno-dev -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=../../netcdf_build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_DLL:BOOL=ON -DENABLE_DLL:BOOL=ON -DENABLE_CDF5:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_HDF4:BOOL=ON -DENABLE_XGETOPT:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_MMAP:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_LOGGING:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTSETS:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_EXTRA_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_LARGE_FILE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_FILTER_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_HDF4_FILE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_UNIT_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING="-fcommon" -S. -Bbuild_shared &&
make -Cbuild_shared install/strip &&
echo SUCCESS
```